# Uncouple azure slot from webapp

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I created an Azure WebApp with 2 slots. **Now I want that the 2 slots aren't coupled to the "main" webapp.** *Is this possible?*

I don't want to create new WebApps, because configuring them cost too much time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "uncouple" deployment slots from the main one however, you can deploy whatever you want in each one so in theory, you can have SiteA in one slot and SiteB in another slot but you'll have to be careful with your app settings as by default, they are shared between slots.

Is this good practice? absolutely not.